# Logic App designer removes foreach loop without error or exception

Tags: json, azure, foreach, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that uses a webhook trigger on a service bus message queue to post selected messages to an API app using a HTTP+Swagger action.

[Azure Logic App Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVpbT.png)

Here’s the json array (DBChanges) from the triggerBody that the foreach is supposed to iterate over

```
"DBChanges":[{"Key":"ItemID","Value":"101"},{"Key":"Description","Value":"Decript the message"},{"Key":"Owner","Value":"Samuel"}]
```

This is the logic app code for the DBChanges POST.  The foreach loop is supposed to iterate over all the elements of the DBChanges array which is a key, value pair in the swagger metadata.

[Azure Logic App Code View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQCVA.png)

When I switch to design mode after adding the foreach loop the designer strips the foreach code out even though it appears syntactically correct.

Does anyone know why the logic app designer strips out the foreach when switching between Design and Code views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update your condition to `"expression": "@equals(triggerBody()['Description'], 'Create')",`.

Within the condition, you want to have a for-each first, then HTTP action inside it, not the other way around (I'm using *Compose* as an example, but you can substitute it to HTTP+Swagger in your case), note how I use @item() to reference each value inside the *DBChanges* array.

```
"actions": {
    "For_each": {
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@item()",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "foreach": "@triggerBody()['DBChanges']",
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "Foreach"
    }
}
```

To help you reference the right value in a JSON blob, we recently added action *Parse JSON*, you can add it after your HTTP Webhook trigger, provide the body as input, and include a schema of the JSON it will be returning. You will be able to use friendly tokens from the picker instead of having to handcraft them. :)

Hope this helps, feel free to reach out to me at Derek.Li (at) Microsoft dot com.

Comment: The code helped me decipher of riddle of how to make the foreach work correctly in my HTTP action.  After implementing, I realized I was do a lot of work to manually reconstruct the input of the previous step when all I actually needed to do was an assignment of the output of the previous step to the input of the next step:  "body": "@json(triggerBody()['ContentData'])".

Comment: One additional comment:  It is still necessary to use the @json function in the expression evaluation or the the parser throws an error correctly stating that the input is json and must be handled as such.